# Chiral centers in albuterol-like compounds

Tags: chirality, amines

[image]

My question is apart from the C in the straight chain with $\ce{-OH}$ group, should $\ce{N}$ be counted as chiral center since it also has tetrahedral geometry and all different substituents?

There are more such examples.

Comment: Also, check out these related questions: [1](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38599/7475), [2](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34466/7475), [3](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/12321/7475) and [4](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16190/7475). Still leaving this open, because I’m not sure if one of these is an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: Inversion at nitrogen chiral centres proceeds rapidly, so the answer is no.

Comment: @orthocresol Would you explain, please?

Comment: Read those related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely count that nitrogen atom as a "chiral center" because it has four different groups attached to it.

However, the net optical activity due to that chiral center is **zero** because the two optical isomers from that nitrogen atom are *rapidly interconverting* with each other ("[Amine inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_inversion)"). They *always* exist as a racemic mixture, and hence are optically inactive.